How to write a const iterator to const std::shared_ptr<const Widget> stored in std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Widget>>?
Suppose I have vector of pointers to objects of class Widget, which are heavy objects with no owner. More often than not, my code needs to iterate over this vector, but needs only access to const Widget.
Is it possible to write the WidgetSet class such that const WidgetSet stores const Widgets? I.e. the iteration over this class yields const std::shared_ptr<const Widget>& objects.
I tried the code below, but came to various issues, highlighted in the comments:
#include <experimental/propagate_const>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Widget {
   void const_method() const {}
   void modify() {}
};

class WidgetSet {
   std::vector<std::experimental::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<Widget>>> _widgets;
  public:
   [[nodiscard]] auto begin() const { return _widgets.cbegin(); }
   [[nodiscard]] auto end() const { return _widgets.cend(); }
   [[nodiscard]] auto begin() { return _widgets.begin(); }
   [[nodiscard]] auto end() { return _widgets.end(); }
};

void delegate_modify(const std::shared_ptr<Widget>& w) {
   w->modify();
}

void exposed_delegate_modify(std::experimental::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<Widget>>& w) {
   //I need to prevent this from compiling and I would not like clients to use types have std::experimental::propagate_const in its name.
   w->modify();
}

void delegate_test(const std::shared_ptr<const Widget>& w) {
   w->const_method();
   // w->modify(); // error, as expected.
}

void test(const WidgetSet cws, WidgetSet ws) {
   for(const auto& w: cws) {
      w->const_method(); // OK
//      w->modify(); // error, as expected.
      delegate_modify(get_underlying(w)); //surprise! this compiles, but shouldn't: w is const!
//      exposed_delegate_modify(w); // error, as expected.
//      delegate_test(w); // error: No matching function for call.
   }
}

I also need this class to interoperate with existing functions that accept std::shared_ptr<const Widget> and std::shared_ptr<Widget> which do not depend on the experimental::propagate_const.

Regarding "I would not like clients to use types have std::experimental::propagate_const in its name" - What about defining using value_type = std::experimental::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<Widget>>; and let users use that? const WidgetSet::value_type& w doesn't look to bad, does it?

@TedLyngmo I know about this option and I would prefer not to. You see, majority of our logic deals with individual Widgets, and WidgetSet is more of an "optional extra". It will confuse everyone in the project if the pointer to individual widget starts to depend on the implementation detail of the WidgetSet. (In this problem area, the const prapagation for the iterator of WidgetSet is an implementation detail).

I know this is normally not recommended - but have you considered using a vector of Widget* instead of shared_ptr?
This will make your code easier to read (no propagate_const) and achieve what you want.
I was also going to suggest to keep using shared_ptr but make an iterator that, upon being dereferenced, returns a Widget* instead of shared_ptr, but this is probably too much work.

@MickaëlC.Guimarães when you defererence a std::vector<Widget *>::const_iterator, you get a Widget * const, not a const Widget *. It has the same const-propogation issue as std::shared_ptr<Widget>

@MickaëlC.Guimarães I cannot have Widget*, because Widgets are shared with Python code via nanobind, and there is no obvious owner of the Widgets. We don't want memory leaks either.


Is it possible to write the WidgetSet class such that const WidgetSet stores const Widgets? I.e. the iteration over this class yields const std::shared_ptr<const Widget>& objects.

No. const std::shared_ptr<const Widget>& is not an object type, it is a reference type. You can construct a std::shared_ptr<const Widget> from a std::shared_ptr<Widget>, but you don't store it anywhere, so returning a reference to that shared ptr isn't safe, it will dangle at the end of the full expression.
It is somewhat suspicious to be writing functions that take std::shared_ptr by const reference. Either they are going to participate in the shared ownership, so you should pass shared_ptr values, or they are observing the pointed-to value, so you should pass references, or pointers (if the stored pointers can be null).
You can write something that unwraps the propogate_const:
class WidgetSet {
   struct get_mutable {
      Widget& operator()(std::experimental::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<Widget>>& ptr) const { return *ptr; }
   };
   struct get_const {
      const Widget& operator()(const std::experimental::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<Widget>>& ptr) const { return *ptr; }
   };
    
   std::vector<std::experimental::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<Widget>>> _widgets;
   decltype(_widgets | std::views::transform(get_mutable{})) _mutable = _widgets | std::views::transform(get_mutable{});
   decltype(_widgets | std::views::transform(get_const{})) _const = _widgets | std::views::transform(get_const{});
  public:
   [[nodiscard]] auto begin() const { return _const.cbegin(); }
   [[nodiscard]] auto end() const { return _const.cend(); }
   [[nodiscard]] auto begin() { return _mutable.begin(); }
   [[nodiscard]] auto end() { return _mutable.end(); }
};

Godbolt link with variations for const Widget * and std::shared_ptr<const Widget>

And that solves my problems! Thank you @Caleth! I've learnt a lot from you today!
